# We are getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function getResource() in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

We are getting **fatal error** in **phtml** page after **paste this code**

```
$cmsstatic = getResource()->getAttribute('size_chart')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($cmsstatic)->tohtml();
```

any body can help please

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: I am trying to implement a dynamic cms block as per this link https://www.milessebesta.com/web-design/magento-use-custom-product-attributes-to-add-cms-static-block-to-product-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected frontend Value of `size_chart` Select box Attribute like below:

```
$sizeChart = $_product->getAttributeText('size_chart');
```

Create Static block that have the same identifier as attribute value and usign below code you can show the static block in template

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeChart)->toHtml();
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I am not getting what I am looking for I want to implement a dynamic cms block as per the product as suggested in this link https://www.milessebesta.com/web-design/magento-use-custom-product-attributes-to-add-cms-static-block-to-product-page/

Comment: I have updated the answer .. hope this help

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I used below mentioned code but its still not working  <?php $sizeChart = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size_chart')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
      echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeChart)->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: Can you confirm you are getting the attribute selected value ?

Comment: No, I am not getting that value, I followed the attached link and pasted your code, but it's throwing the FATAL ERROR, the same which was earlier, I am able to select the static block on backend but on frontend it does not display

Comment: In which file you have added the code. could you please confirm you are getting Product object. You can check product Id is coming or not `$_product->getId()`

Comment: I tried it on view.phtml and I am getting the product and data, but after implementation of above code the fatal error is showing.

Comment: try updated code and check `size_chart` attribute is set to show on product detail page

Comment: I have created a dropdown attribute to select the static block at product edit

Comment: I am sure you are not gettign fatal error now. Just check `Visisble on product view page on frontend` set to yes for `size_chart` attribute in manage attribute section